# PowerShell Delete folder if exists

Tags: powershell

Could you help me again with a powershell script?
I want to check if multiple folders exist, if they exist then delete the complete folder.
Also provide information if the folder has been deleted or information if the folder does not exist.

I now use the script below for multiple files. (thanks to good help)
I want to use the same script for 1 or more folders.
For example, delete folder c:\test1\ and c:test2
Folders may be deleted, even if they still contain files.

```
$paths =  "c:\test\1.txt", "c:\test\2.txt", "c:\test\3.txt"
foreach($filePath in $paths)
{
    if (Test-Path $filePath) {
        Remove-Item $filePath -verbose
    } else {
        Write-Host "Path doesn't exits"
    }
}
```

I'm not super handy with powershell, hope you can help me with this again.

Thanks
Tom

Comment: Did you try replacing the `$paths` with paths to 1 or more folders? What happens if you do?

Comment: Hi Mathias, i already tried that. Unfortunately it doesn't work. It still expects a file.

Comment: But what _happens_? Does it throw an error? If yes, please post the error message, in full.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- To remove a directory (folder) that *has content*, you must use the `-Recurse`  switch with [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item) - otherwise, an *interactive confirmation prompt* is presented.
- A given path existing doesn't necessarily mean that it is a *directory* - it may be a *file*. To specifically test if a given path is a directory / file, use `-PathType Container` / `-PathType Leaf` with [`Test-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path).
- While only strictly necessary when paths happen to contain `[` characters, the robust way to pass *literal* paths is via the `-LiteralPath` parameter that file-processing cmdlets support - by contrast, the first *positional* argument typically binds to the `-Path` parameter (e.g., `Test-Path foo` is the same as `Test-Path -Path foo`), which interprets its argument(s) as [wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards).

Applied to your use case (note that no attempt is made to distinguish files from directories):

```
# Input directory paths.
$paths = 'c:\test1', 'c:\test2', 'c:\test3'
foreach ($path in $paths) {
    if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $path) {
      Remove-Item -LiteralPath $path -Verbose -Recurse -WhatIf
    } else {
      "Path doesn't exist: $path"
    }
}
```

<sup>Note: The [**`-WhatIf`** common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above ***previews* the operation**. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

---

Another, more efficient option is to use [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item) to get objects representing the file-system items, if they exist, and pipe them to `Remove-Item`:

```
$paths = 'c:\test1', 'c:\test2', 'c:\test3'

Get-Item -LiteralPath $paths -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable errs |
  Remove-Item -Recurse -Verbose -WhatIf

if ($errs) {
  "The following path(s) do not exist: $($errs.TargetObject)"
}
```

Note the use of `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to silence errors resulting from nonexistent paths, and `-ErrorVariable errs` in order to collect these errors in self-chosen variable `$errs`.

The `.TargetObject` property of the  `[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` instances collected in `$errs` then contains the path that triggered the error, resolved to a full path.

Comment: Ofc the "bold uppercase" were meant ironically. ;) Anyway I guess adding some emphasis to the note about WhatIf is a good thing. :)